# PHP variables not being passed to functions with include/require

Tags: php, function, variables, scope, require

I'm trying to make an easy function for including file, but for some reason, the variables aren't being passed to.

In the file test.php:

```
<?php
function parse($template) {
    require $template;
}

$test = "test";
parse("stuff.php");
?>
```

And the file stuff.php:

```
<?php
echo $test;
?>
```

And I'll get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: test in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testinggrounds/stuff.php on line 2
```

However, if I replace this statement in test.php

```
parse("stuff.php");
```

with

```
require "stuff.php";
```

And it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why make a function when she exist ?

You have just to call `require 'stuff.php';` and that's all

Comment: I know. I wanted to put $path and $ext inside the function so all I need was to call parse("script") and it'll include path/script.php. If there's really no other way, then I'll do what you said earlier.

But thanks anyway! :)